# How to prevent Android app's running service from being killed every time I install a new version of the app?

Tags: android, apk, android-service

It seems that every time I install an updated version of my app, the installation procedure kills any running services from the old app.
Is there a way to install a new version of an app without automatically killing an existing running service from that app?

Comment: No, sorry. Upgrading an app includes terminating its process, so that the next process can get the updated code.